# Releasing DB connections back to the pool?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, transactions

In a Java EE environment, I have defined 2 datasources pointing to 2 databases.
Drivers that are used support XA transactions.

If i start a transaction that will involve both Db's

```
StartXaTran (){
Updatedb1();
UpdateDb2();
}
```

When the connection from db1 will be returned to the pool ?

After the first method ot at the end of the Xa transaction?

Thanks

Comment: For me it make sense the second option....during some experiments i noticed the first one....